# LuisResult is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a LUIS dialog and it successfully detects the intent and call the specified child dialog.

```
[Serializable]
[LuisModel("xxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")]
public class RootDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    [LuisIntent("ApplyJob")]
    public async Task Search(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity,LuisResult result)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Lets apply for a job");
        context.Call(new ApplyJobDialog(result), ApplyJobComplete);

    }

    private async Task ApplyJobComplete(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        context.Done(await result);
    }
}
```

I am passing the LuisResult to the child dialog. (so, i can extract some entities in the child dialog. - Not implemented in the following code)

My child Dialog looks like this

```
[Serializable]
public class ApplyJobDialog: IDialog<object>
{
    public LuisResult LuisResult { get; set; }

    internal ApplyJobDialog(LuisResult result)
    {
        LuisResult = result;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("hello");
        context.Wait(AfterComplete);
    }

    private async Task AfterComplete(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        context.Done("");
    }
}
```

It shows "hello" to the user.But then it throws an exception. (Displayed in emulator) Even without using the passed "LuisResult"

```
Exception: Type ‘Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models.LuisResult’ in Assembly ‘Microsoft.Bot.Builder, 
Version=3.11.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35’ is not marked as serializable.
[File of type 'text/plain']
```

However if I am not calling the "AfterComplete", It does not throws an exception.

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
    await context.PostAsync("hello");
    //context.Wait(AfterComplete);
    context.Done("");
}
```

What am i doing wrong here. How can i call ResumeAfter methods (like AfterComplete) and continue the conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LuisResult` class is not serializable, so you cannot hold a variable in the `ApplyJobDialog`, because the dialog will try to be serialized.

You will have to pass something serializable or extract the entities in the `RootDialog`.

Comment: You are correct. I extracted entities in RootDialog and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Ezequiel, I have same issue and i want to extract entities in childDialog only. How can i achieve this.